# Can't get data from Google Places

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdata, nsurl, google-places-api

I am trying to get the google places API to work on my iPhone project.  Now, I had it working about an hour ago, but I can't seem to figure out what I did to make it stop working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
- (NSString *)searchString {
    // this mutable string allows me to dynamically create the search string
    // we start with the static part of the api search URL
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location="];

    // since I need to get the user's location, I need to create a location manager
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    // we need to now update the current location,
    // otherwise there will be no coordinates
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // now that it's updated, we stop it because I
    // am not tracking anything
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // this appends the lattitude/longitude, as double values, into the URL
    [result appendFormat:@"%g,%g", [[locationManager location] coordinate].latitude, [[locationManager location] coordinate].longitude];

    // release the location manager for memory management
    [locationManager release];

    // if a filter is present, add the keyword item to try to filter
    // the results
    if([[self filterString] length] > 0) {
        [result appendFormat:@"&keyword=%@", filterString];
    }

    // add the rest of the validated URL now
    //[result appendString:@"&types=food|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|restaurant&rankby=distance&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyBmO_f6h4_Q0xArw6tdxUF7TH7rZpaiFfQ"];
    [result appendString:@"&types=food&rankby=distance&sensor=true&key=mykey"];

    // log the result for testing
    NSLog(@"Completed Search String: %@", result);

    return result;

}
```

Now, when I look at my log, copy the 'completed search string' into Safari, it brings up the results that I need.

But if I use the following code, the app hangs:

```
- (void)performSearch {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self searchString]]]; // hangs on this line!

    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [data objectFromJSONData];
    NSArray *resultsArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"results"];

    currentList = [ARGooglePlace placesWithArray:resultsArray];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I think I should mention that I am using the JSONKit to do the JSON parsing.  Also, the ARGooglePlace is a custom class that isn't relevant right now (it doesn't even get there...)

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the location manager and the lat/long out of the searchString method...  just put it in the performSearch method.  And instead, pass the lat/long as received from location manager into searchString.

It sounds like a timing issue with your location manager.  It could have been working earlier b/c location manager had previously cached location data... and was able to grab the correct coords.

2+ Possible scenarios:

1) problem with location manager not updating it's coords and just hanging there
2) google website being the culprit (maybe loading too much data??)

Pulling location manager out of the searchString method will help isolate cause... and one can just pass lat/long values directly to test google website as well.

Comment: Please don't use extra signatures for your posts: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: It may have been an issue with Google then, as it started working again.

Comment: Yeah, I found out it was actually my device.  Once I restarted the device, the problem went away.